# Joining two Tables in PL/SQL and obtain the required result

Tags: plsql

Structure of two tables in the database are as below.

1) Department table:
Dept_Id number(5) primary key,
Sept_Name varchar2(20),
Employee_strength number(4) not null.

2)Employee table:
E_Id number(5),
E_Name varchar2(20),
Designation varchar2(20),
D_ID number(5) references Department table Dept_ID.

A pl/sql program block to print the name the departments which has employees having the designation as "SE" is to be written and if no record in the department table fulfilling the given conditions found ,code should print the message "No record found" and if the record found code has to print Department name.

Please Help.

Comment: In order to help, people expect you to share tried code.

Comment: How are the tables linked? Please supply create tables commands. What is the data in those tables?

Comment: No tables are provided only clue is given that D_ID number(5)  of Employee table references Department table Dept_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option (based on tables similar to yours; these belong to Scott).

I'll search for a **SALESMAN**.

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL> select distinct d.deptno, e.job
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno, e.job;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
           MANAGER
           PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST
           CLERK
           MANAGER
        30 CLERK
           MANAGER
           SALESMAN        --> only department 30 has SALESMEN
        40

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_exists number(1);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_d in (select d.deptno, d.dname from dept d order by d.deptno) loop
  5      select max(1)
  6        into l_exists
  7        from emp e
  8        where e.deptno = cur_d.deptno
  9          and e.job = 'SALESMAN';
 10
 11      dbms_output.put_line(cur_d.deptno || ' - ' ||
 12                           case when l_exists = 1 then cur_d.dname
 13                                else  'no record found'
 14                           end);
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
10 - no record found
20 - no record found
30 - SALES
40 - no record found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct department names then use the `distinct()` function in the SQL query.

I am using inner join to query the two table based on they have the same department id and department name is "SE".

Here are the steps to be followed:

1. declare the block(anonymous in this case)
2. write the SQL query for the cursor
3. begin the block
4. open the cursor
5. fetch the rows from the cursor
6. print the result
7. close the cursor
8. if the cursor doesn't contain any rows, so check for this condition
9. close the block

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR C IS SELECT distinct(D.DEPT_NAME) FROM DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.DEPT_ID = E.D_ID AND E.DESIGNATION LIKE 'SE';
  RES C%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN C;

     loop
       FETCH C INTO RES;
       EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RES.DEPT_NAME);
     end loop;
    IF(C%ROWCOUNT=0) then
       dbms_output.put_line('No record found'); 
    end if;

END;  
/
```